# apache2 - multiple subdomains, each one served via reverse proxy against different local ports

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, apache-2.4, httpd, ubuntu-16.04

I have the following local services located in a server with IP 198.51.100.1:

```
127.0.0.1:5000 - special pda service
127.0.0.1:8888 - www service
```

I have configured the following DNS entries:

```
foo.com - A - 198.51.100.1
pda.foo.com - A - 198.51.100.1
www.foo.com - A - 198.51.100.1
```

The idea is that if user types `pda.foo.com` site will proxy against `127.0.0.1:5000` via `SSL` and that if user types `www.foo.com` site will proxy against `127.0.0.1:8888` via `SSL`.

I have the following config as the only `sites-enabled` config file:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName pda.foo.com
        Redirect permanent / https://pda.foo.com
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName www.foo.com
        Redirect permanent / https://www.foo.com
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>

NameVirtualHost *:443
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>

        ServerName pda.foo.com

        SSLProxyEngine On
        ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:5000/
        ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:5000/

        SSLEngine On
        SSLCertificateFile  /etc/letsencrypt/live/server2.foobar.com/fullchain.pem
        SSLCertificateKeyFile       /etc/letsencrypt/live/server2.foobar.com/privkey.pem

</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>

        ServerName www.foo.com

        SSLProxyEngine On
        ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8888/
        ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8888/

        SSLEngine On
        SSLCertificateFile  /etc/letsencrypt/live/server2.foobar.com/fullchain.pem
        SSLCertificateKeyFile       /etc/letsencrypt/live/server2.foobar.com/privkey.pem

</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

This is shown when you do `apachectl -t -D DUMP_VHOSTS`:

```
AH00548: NameVirtualHost has no effect and will be removed in the next release /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/mysite.conf:1
VirtualHost configuration:
*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
         default server pda.foo.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/mysite.conf:4)
         port 80 namevhost pda.foo.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/mysite.conf:4)
         port 80 namevhost www.foo.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/mysite.conf:10)
*:443                  is a NameVirtualHost
         default server pda.foo.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/mysite.conf:20)
         port 443 namevhost pda.foo.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/mysite.conf:20)
         port 443 namevhost www.foo.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/mysite.conf:47)
```

When I try to access www.foo.com I get site not found delivered by the DNS service provider.

When I try to access pda.foo.com it redirects to SSL but again I get site not found delivered by service provider.

Any tips?

Comment: Do **NOT** use `9.9.9.9` as a "fake" IP for your documentation purposes as it is a totally normal and live IP, used for a big public DNS service. Use guidance in RFC5737 to obfuscate IPv4 addresses.

Comment: @patrick-mevzek duly noted and edited as per RFC5737

Comment: Thanks, I have retracted my downvote to salute your efforts... Next step is RFC2606 to properly obfuscate name, basically use `example.com` instead of `foo.com` or any other name. Sorry not to have bring that up previously.

Comment: "I get site not found delivered by the DNS service provider", can you detail exactly what happens? Is it a DNS issue, or does the request reach you apache server?

Comment: I was stuck at the Apache site, but finally I realized that my IP was not properly set up in the DNS side. I was looking for a configuration mistake and while doing that I did not realize that it was a simple IP typo. thanks